# magento product alert should disappear when already subscribed

Tags: magento, alert, product

Please I need help about a topic of a couple of years ago.I need to retrieve product subscription alerts (if a customer has already sent a product alert, he should not be able to send it twice, so the alert for this product should disappear for this customer). I found this

```
$customer_product_alerts = 
Mage::getModel('productalert/stock')->getCollection()>addFieldToFilter ('customer_id', $customer_id);
```

in a precedent discussion but I don't know where to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

use this code to get all the products of a customer subscribed.

```
$customer_id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
if($customer_id) {
    $customer_stock_alerts = Mage::getModel('productalert/stock')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer_id);
    $i = 0;
    $product_ids = array();
    foreach ( $customer_stock_alerts as $alert )
    {
     $product_ids[i] = $alert->getProductId();
     $i++;
    }
}
```

You will all the product ids of the current customer.

Check the product id with the customer subscribed product ids using `in_array` method. If true hide the block else show the block.
That will look some thing like below.

```
if(!in_array($_product->getId(),$product_ids))
{
    echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls');
}
```

Hope helps you,
Thanks.